# Можно ли для таблицы YDB делать много вторичных индексов

Tags: ydb

Насколько замедлится работа с таблицей, если на неё сделать много (например 10) вторичных индексов?

Answer (score 0):

Так делать настоятельно не рекомендуется:

При чтении данных замедления не будет.

А вот при записи будет в 10 раз больше записей, и минимум 10 шардов в транзакции.
Лучше создавать не больше 5 индексов.